# OAuth: Should an unexpired access token be revoked when it is refreshed?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth

Typically an access token is refreshed (using a refresh token) when it is expired. However, it's possible to refresh an unexpired token. I understand the requirements for revoking the refresh token as part of this process, but what I can't make out from [the specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-6) is whether the associated *access token* should be revoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the oauth2 spec, as far as I can tell this is indeed not required. This has some advantages because it lets you do a refresh before your original access token expired, and you can continue to use this token until you get a fresh one.

tl;dr: No I don't think it's need to expire them, and I think this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a nice feature to make access tokens revokable. But it's quite hard to implement in practice, assuming the system needs high availability and scalability.

There are two main options how access tokens are managed.

First is via a central database. In that case, to validate a token, this database has to be queried. With such central database, it's quite easy to revoke any tokens. But the problem is that this central storage is hard to scale and keep available. It is very rarely when this type of solution is used in practice.

The second approach is to have a self-contained access token. This is by far the most common approach. Such token can be validated without talking to a central storage/service. This makes the system truly scalable and available.

The problem with the second approach is that there is no way to revoke an access token. This is the trade off we do - scale/availability vs revocation support.

Systems tend to mitigate the absence of revocation by making TTL for access tokens very short. Hence, these systems may block access token being refreshed.

Comment: The _vast_ majority of systems could check a Redis server for valid access tokens with ease and it wouldn't break a sweat. If you are in that 0.01% of applications that extremely large and this is an issue, you're probably not in a category where you need to ask this question, and if your issue is designed in a way where this is an issue, you may have designed it incorrectly.

Comment: I suspect that this is yet another bad use of JWT tokens, even though you didn't explicitly mention this. https://evertpot.com/jwt-is-a-bad-default/

Comment: I wouldn't go that far as stating that that's a JWT thing :) - as you mentioned in your answer, the rfc (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.4) specifically says that the token could be whatever.